# Polygon won't fill in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am having difficulty getting Google Earth to fill in polygons. *The outline of the polygon is displayed, but it is not filled in.* I have found other similar questions where the fix is to remove `innerBoundaryIs` tags, or to remove loops in the boundary, but I don't think either of those fixes are relevant here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
        <name>polygon3.kml</name>
        <Style id="examplePolyStyle">
                <PolyStyle>
                        <color>ffffff00</color>
                        <outline>0</outline>
                </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id="examplePolyStyle0">
                <Pair>
                        <key>normal</key>
                        <styleUrl>#examplePolyStyle1</styleUrl>
                </Pair>
                <Pair>
                        <key>highlight</key>
                        <styleUrl>#examplePolyStyle</styleUrl>
                </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Style id="examplePolyStyle1">
                <PolyStyle>
                        <color>ffffff00</color>
                        <outline>0</outline>
                </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
                <name>Untitled Polygon</name>
                <styleUrl>#examplePolyStyle0</styleUrl>
                <Polygon>
                        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                                <LinearRing>
                                        <coordinates>
                                                -74.19398870115191,48.21138137082842,0 -74.53662724779845,47.79378794242044,0 -73.97895911455657,47.72309262210254,0 -74.19398870115191,48.21138137082842,0 
                                        </coordinates>
                                </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Here's information about the version of Google Earth I'm using:

```
Google Earth 7.1.8.3036 (64-bit)
Build Date 1/17/2017
Build Time 8:57:31 am
Renderer OpenGL
Operating System Linux (3.13.0.0)
Video Driver Intel Open Source Technology Center
Max Texture Size 8192x8192
available video memoryinformation not available
Server kh.google.com
```

Comment: What is exact problem? KML example produces a filled-in polygon. InnerBoundaryIs tags are optional.

Comment: When I load the above example into Google Earth, the outline of the polygon is displayed, but it is not filled in. I've clarified this in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with my graphics card driver. When I started Google Earth, I got a message about clamped polygons only being shown in outline mode. At the time, I didn't know what a "clamped polygon" was, so when I tried to create some polygons I didn't make the connection. Just now, when I restarted Google Earth, I understood the message.

There is a [question on another forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753833/google-earth-graphics-card-problem-in-ubuntu-14-04-64bit) on how to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics issue so change from OpenGL to Direct.

Go to "Tools" , then "Options", then "3D view", and select "DirectX".

I had similar problem and change from OpenGL to DirectX and it worked.

Hope this step solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but different cause. I found when I had custom image overlays that these clashed with filled and filled+outline polygons. The solution was to make sure that the overlays have a positive, non-zero altitude, and are measured relative to the ground.

When the overlays have the "clamped to ground" setting chosen then they no longer appear if the custom image overlay is shown at the same time.

[image: Polygon settings dialog]